# CSS Content property not working on Firefox

Tags: css, wordpress

I am trying to override the logo image in a WordPress site but I see that the `content` CSS property works on Chrome but not on Firefox.

I also tried using `:before` and `:after` but probably I am missing something.

This is the page: https://www.exploringart.co/contact-page/

And this is the CSS I am using:

```
 body.elementor-page-4930 #site-logo #site-logo-inner a img {
  content:url("....logo_white.png");
 }
```

Comment: What is the full path of `logo_white.png`? In your code snippet, you have `....`which is not a correct path so we can't help you. I see on your live site the path 'https://www.exploringart.co/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/logo_white.png' which leads to a 404 error page.

Comment: CSS content won't use a URL (I've recently run across this issue trying something on one of my own projects). Content will also not work on an `img` tag.  If you want to use CSS to display an image, you will want use `background` or `background-image`, but then you will run into issues with image clipping, which would still require JS to fetch the the original image size, produce an aspect ratio, and set container with the `background` to the determined aspect ratio. Whats the use-case that a logo would need to be dynamic in this way through CSS?

Comment: Content URL does not works on Firefox, use Background CSS or Javascript to change SRC

Answer (score 0):

You need to use JavaScript in order to modify `src` attribute of your image :

```
document.getElementById('your-image-id').src = 'path-to-your-image/logo_white.png';
```

or with jQuery :

```
$(".page-id-4930 .custom-logo-link img").attr("src","path-to-your-image/logo_white.png");
```

To target you contact page :

Notice the `.page-id-4930`: it targets your contact page, it is the id of your WordPress page.

An other approach would be php :

1. Modify the template, remove the `img` and insert your logo with css `background-image`. Then, in css, it's easy to target your page and change the background image.
2. You could make an if statement :

if it is page id=4930 show that image, else show normal image.

```
if (page_id = 4930) {
    // show image_contact 
} else {
    // show image_normal
}
```

Comment: Ok, but if I have to do it only in a specific page is ti better to do it with css or js?

Comment: CSS is not how you would want to handle this use-case. You can use add JS that would use `window.location` and then maybe use a REGEX to check if the user is on one of the specific pages, then set your updated image in the manner that Sebastien showed here.

Comment: I am not very good with JS but what is the correct eventListener type?

Comment: @user14649759 of course : you can easily target a specific page (your contact page) with jQuery. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have to do it in JS, Idon't have jquery